# Watch controller model value from inside directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to have angular watch the `$viewValue` of a controller from inside a directive.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dkrotts/TfTr5/5/

```
function foo($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.bar = "Lorem ipsum";

    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.bar = "Dolor sit amet";
    }, 2000);
}

myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            scope.$watch(controller.$viewValue, function() {
                console.log("Changed to " + controller.$viewValue);
            });
        }
    } 
});
```

As is, the $watch function is not catching the model change done after 2 seconds from inside the controller. What am I missing?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`$watch` accepts the "name" of the property to watch in the scope, you're asking it to watch the value. Change it to watch `attrs.ngModel` which returns "bar", now you're watching `scope.bar`. You can get the value the same way you were or use `scope[attrs.ngModel]` which is like saying `scope["bar"]` which again, is the same as `scope.bar`.

```
scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newValue) {
    console.log("Changed to " + newValue);
});
```

To clarify user271996's comment: `scope.$eval` is used because you may pass object notation into the `ng-model` attribute. i.e. `ng-model="someObj.someProperty"` which won't work because `scope["someObj.someProperty"]` is not valid. `scope.$eval` is used to evaluate that string into an actual object so that `scope["someObj.someProperty"]` becomes `scope.someObj.someProperty`.

Comment: Working fiddle since SO no longer likes fiddles in the answer: http://jsfiddle.net/TfTr5/7/

Comment: I think as long as you include a code sample somewhere in your answer SO will allow the fiddle link.

Comment: ok, except that there should be console.log("Changed to " + scope.$eval(attrs.ngModel));

Comment: scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newValue) {
            console.log("Changed to " + newValue);
 });

Comment: Ha, yea that is simpler isn't it? I must have just been thinking based on the original question's example.

Answer (score 9):

Wanted to add: in 1.2.x, with isolated scope, the above wont work. http://jsfiddle.net/TfTr5/23/

A workaround I came up with was using the fact that $watch also accepts a function, so you can access your controller using that.

```
scope.$watch(
    function(){return controller.$viewValue},
    function(newVal, oldVal){
        //code
    }
)
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TfTr5/24/

If anyone has an alternative, I would gladly welcome it!

Comment: If the scope is isolated then you can't go watching things in the parent scope. This is just as hacky but I think a little clearer to understand: http://jsfiddle.net/TfTr5/25/ basically just do the watch on the parent scope. If you require ngModel, and your scope is isolated, it should be safe. `link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            scope.$parent.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function() {
             console.log("Changed to " + scope.$parent[attrs.ngModel]);
            });
        }` but in general i wouldn't isolate something that needs to watch $parent scope.

Comment: I totally agree with you Johnathan. Your solution also works but correct me if I'm wrong, $viewValue isnt necessarily the same as the model value right? see here: http://jsfiddle.net/TfTr5/27/ I believe if you are using angular's form validation, it doesn't update ngModel unless the $viewValue passes the validator. By the way, here's another solution that watches ngModel - but not $viewValue - that is a bit cleaner http://jsfiddle.net/TfTr5/26

Comment: Yea, I forgot the original question was about the viewValue and if the scope is isolated then you can bi-diretionally bind ngModel which on the scope so your latest fiddle is good.

Comment: @JonathanRowny please add an answer instead of commenting :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bind a value inside isolated scope,there are 2 ways to do it.The first way you can use even you don't have isolated scope.Here are the ways:

1) use `$attrs.any_attribute` and bind it (set in watch)

2) use **2 ways binding ('=')** method and set it into listener

if you want more with examples here is a great article

http://www.w3docs.com/snippets/angularjs/bind-variable-inside-angularjs-directive-isolated-scope.html

Answer (score -1):

If you want debounce on a model value, it is worth mentioning the debounce setting in **ng-model-option**:

```
<input type="text" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }" ng-model="search"/>
```

For example: this watch is trigger 1000 ms after change and reset at new changes.

```
scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newValue) { });
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Comment: how is debounce related?