# $watch ngModel from inside directive using isolate scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to watch my model value from inside my linking function.

```
scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function() {
       console.log("Changed"); 
    });
```

When I change the model value inside my controller, the $watch function is not triggered.

```
$scope.myModel = "ACT";

$timeout(function() {
   $scope.myModel = "TOTALS"; 
}, 2000);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dkrotts/BtrZH/4/

What am I missing here?

Comment: FYI, the reason that watching attrs.ngModel worked [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567908/watch-controller-model-value-from-inside-directive) is because the directive was not creating a new scope.  In this question, your directive is creating an isolate scope, so you need to watch something in that isolate scope.

Comment: ... or you could just watch the model value and not worry about who's scope is what. :P haha.

Comment: @blesh, I'm actively reading around trying to determine if I like your solution better than what dnc253 provided.  I have to say that I'm not keen on having to `require: ngModel` and write a function in the $watch, vs just `$watch('model', ...`.  +1 for both of you though.

Comment: @MarkRajcok Haha... it really doesn't matter. The most important thing is that it *works and is maintainable*. dnc's solution was perfectly fine, and I might use his in a lot of cases. However, if someone comes here actively looking for a solution for how to watch the modelValue specifically on ngModel (which is what the title of the question reads like), I wanted to provide that answer for them.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The problem is that you `$watch`ing `attrs.ngModel` which is equal to "myModel". You do not have "myModel" bound in your scope. You want to `$watch` "model". That is what is bound in the scope of your directive. See http://jsfiddle.net/BtrZH/5/

Answer (score 153):

You'll need to watch a function that returns the $modelValue you're watching.

The following code shows a basic example:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function (){
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
           scope.$watch(function () {
              return ngModel.$modelValue;
           }, function(newValue) {
               console.log(newValue);
           });
        }
     };
});
```

[Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/N2dfF6aW8hVt0yAcQuIG?p=preview) of the same idea in action.

Comment: +1 for your answer as well. Both answers really are correct. Mine provided a solution to the specific problem linked in the question, whereas yours provides a general solution for those looking for a way to `$watch` what is specified in ngModel.

Comment: If I try using an isolate scope with this solution, it only works if I use `scope: { name: '=ngModel' }`.  If I try to use a different isolate scope property name -- e.g., `scope: { model: '=ngModel' }` -- it doesn't work!?  Maybe when the ngModelController first runs it somehow knows about the name in the HTML/view??

Comment: @MarkRajcok: That's pretty weird, I don't get such an error. Is it possible you have a parent scope interfering with that name?

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/AXBut/1/) that shows what happens if you use a different name in the object hash than what ng-model uses in the HTML.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/14792601

Comment: That has to be a bug. It's probably not a common circumstance.

Comment: Okay, the more I think about this, the more I think it's because the ngModel controller is set up against the parent scope. And when it updates the parent scope, it's not doing so in a way that triggers the watches associated with the bidirectional binding in your directive.  It's still weird though, and I'm only speculating.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me with isolated scope. I changed this line: `return ngModel.$modelValue;` to `return scope.ngModel;` and it's working fine. Maybe it helps someone.

Comment: @Lucasus what version of Angular?

Comment: @blesh version 1.2.0-rc.2

Comment: Yeah, things have changed a bit, this answer was for 1.0.X ... 2 minor versions different means a lot in this case.

Comment: Note that the original solution did not work because there was a missing return statement. I have correct the problem.

Comment: Can you explain why `$modelValue` instead of `$viewValue`? (it works with both)

Answer (score 23):

The proper way to do this is:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

        ngModel.$render = function () {
            var newValue = ngModel.$viewValue;
            console.log(newValue)
        };

    }
  };
});
```

Comment: This binding work one time! I tried to bind ngModel to [nouiSlider](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/) component. And this solved my circular binding problem. Thanks!

Comment: It works because every time angular detects a change in this elements model it will call [$render](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$render) to update it, so here we replace the original $render function to do whatever we want it to do.

Comment: @TimoHuovinen What does the original $render function do?

Comment: @HugoBaés - this is not always the case.  For instance when using this on an input element, many [input types](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/65f800e19ec669ab7d5abbd2f6b82bf60110651a/src/ng/directive/input.js) implement $render to correctly set the value shown to the user

Answer (score 8):

Here is another way to do this:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function (){
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
           attrs.$observe('ngModel', function(value){ // Got ng-model bind path here
              scope.$watch(value,function(newValue){ // Watch given path for changes
                  console.log(newValue);  
              });
           });
        }
    };
});
```

Doing it that way you will be able to listen value changes with binds like that

Answer (score 4):

This is an extension of @ Emmanuel's answer above to answer @Martin Velez, although I know it's pretty late! (Also I can't make comments yet, so if this isn't the right place for this, sorry!)

I'm not sure which version of Angular OP was using, but in Angular#1.2+ at least on the official docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$render, $render is listed like this:

> Called when the view needs to be updated. It is expected that the user
>   of the ng-model directive will implement this method.
>
> The $render() method is invoked in the following situations:
>
> $rollbackViewValue() is called. If we are rolling back the view value
>   to the last committed value then $render() is called to update the
>   input control. The value referenced by ng-model is changed
>   programmatically and both the $modelValue and the $viewValue are
>   different from last time. Since ng-model does not do a deep watch,
>   $render() is only invoked if the values of $modelValue and $viewValue
>   are actually different from their previous value.

I interpret this to mean that the correct way to $watch an ngModel from a directive is to require ngModel and implement a link function that injects ngModelController. Then use the ngModel API that's built in to $render-on-change ($watch), or whatever else.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do it.

1) You can use `$attrs.[any_attribute]` and set on it any listener

2) You can have isolated scope with **2 ways binding** variable and set a listener on it.If you want more,here is a cool article

http://www.w3docs.com/snippets/angularjs/bind-variable-inside-angularjs-directive-isolated-scope.html