# Making ngModel fire $render even when bound to deeper objects or arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

When binding to to ngModel, if you have an object:

```
scope.someObj = { 
    prop: 10, 
    prop2: [20, 30], 
    subObj: {
        prop: 40
    } 
}
```

and you attach it to some input fields like so:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="someObj.prop" />
<input type="number" ng-model="someObj.prop2[0]" />
<input type="number" ng-model="someObj.prop2[1]" />
<input type="number" ng-model="someObj.subObj.prop" />
```

And put an event listener to the $render trigger of each of them, like so:

```
ngModel.$render = function() {console.log("Hello");};
```

The $render will only fire then the first input is edited, but never when the others are. Basically, the $render doesn't trigger on models bound to anything deeper than one level.

Is there a way to force it to do so?

Comment: This is odd. How do you add the `$render()` method? I presume that you've a custom directive, right? Could you provide a live code example with plunker?

Comment: Yes, it all happens in a custom directive. It's all part of this discussion really: https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/issues/252 Working on a plunker now, will update OP when done.

Comment: This is why (and I have no idea why they are executing it inside the watcher function and not the callback): https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/a22596c925a41c6f9b78cb21e18894987bbbc84b/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1084

Comment: For some reason, it actually works when I test it in this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/8A3K1Jxjs7q03FYMXkQA?p=preview  testing further...

Answer (score 2):

I used $scope.$watch to monitor it.

```
<input ng-model="myInputs.a">
<input ng-model="myInputs.b">

var obj = {};

$scope.$watch('myInputs', function(){
   // do whatever here ....
   // you can assign variables to myInputs
   obj.x = myInputs.a;

   }, true);
```

The key here is to add the last parameter `true`, so it deep monitors your object.

Comment: Watch helps, as evident by this: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-slider/blob/master/src/slider.js#L48 Can you update your code to use attributes.ngModel instead of 'someObj' so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: I don't think watching attributes.ngModel will work. You either need to bind myInput in your scope and watch it or watch a function that returns myInput. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693052/watch-ngmodel-from-inside-directive-using-isolate-scope

Comment: yoonchee - usually you would watch the models inside a controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution goes [like this](http://plnkr.co/edit/XkEy6mSOiON51r3tc95p?p=preview):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.7"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="number" ng-model="someObj.prop" />
    <input type="number" ng-model="someObj.prop2[0]" />
    <input type="number" ng-model="someObj.prop2[1]" />
    <input type="number" ng-model="someObj.subObj.prop" />
  </body>

</html>
```