# Use a $formatter on a object typed ngModel value with angular 1.2 worked, but not with version 1.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parsing, angular-ngmodel

This code worked with angular-1.2.26, but not with angular-1.3.0.rc5 (or any 1.3.x versions I tried).

I found this issue https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9218 on angular's github, but I am not familiar with github interface and I cannot figure out if the bug is confirmed or if the behavior is expected, if it has been fixed or not; and if yes, what version should I take.

JSFiddles :

- [with angular v1.2.26, ngModel as object](http://fiddle.jshell.net/msieurtoph/jqL301zz/)
- [with angular v1.3.0.rc5, ngModel as object](http://fiddle.jshell.net/msieurtoph/brnz04pp/)

For each, I expect to have 'my label' in the input when loading the page. It works for the first one, but not for the second.

And look at the console to see what value is passed to the formatter.

HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl as c">
    <input my-dir ng-model="c.foobar" />
    <pre>{{c.foobar | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

JS :

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function(){
    this.foobar = {
        value : 'my value',
        label : 'my label'
    }
})


.directive('myDir', function(){
    return {
        restrict :'A',
        require:'ngModel',
        link : function(scope, elt, attrs, modelCtrl){

            // conversion "view -> model"
            modelCtrl.$parsers.unshift( function(value){
                console.log('Value:', value);
                return {label:value, value:value};
            })

            // conversion "model -> view"
            modelCtrl.$formatters.unshift(function formatter(modelValue){
                console.log('modelValue:', modelValue);
                return modelValue.label;
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In 1.3 you should be doing it like this (which will also work in 1.2):

```
.directive('myDir', function(){
    return {
        restrict :'A',
        require:'ngModel',
        link : function(scope, elt, attrs, modelCtrl){
            
            // conversion "view -> model"
            modelCtrl.$parsers.push( function(value){
                console.log('Value:', value);
                return {label:value, value:value};
            })
            
            // conversion "model -> view"
            modelCtrl.$formatters.push(function formatter(modelValue){
                console.log('modelValue:', modelValue);
                return modelValue.label;
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Because if you `unshift` your `$formatter` in 1.3, then you will get the stringified value of the model, if you want to have access to the non stringified value of the model, you will have to put your `$formatter` at the end (`push`).

I know that this contradicts [this comment](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9218#issuecomment-57350538) of Igor Minar.

> The breaking change is that the viewValue passed into formatters will
> be a toString version of the formatted modelValue. So if any custom
> formatters execute after the default formatter, they'll see the string
> version of the value. If any formatter needs access to the value
> before it was stringified, the formatter should be registered via
> $formatters.unshift(customFormatter).

But **[things changed after that comment](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9218#issuecomment-57398109)**.

## [Example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/dctf1p8e/)

Comment: so, if I understand (and rtfm), using 1.3, I should `push` formatters and `unshift` parsers. I thought I tried, but maybe not be the with r5 version ... Anyway, thx a lot.

Comment: Hooray for finding the workaround, but it's so counterintuitive. How the heck can the first formatter get the stringified object, and then the last formatter get the actual object?! Unless, they are executed in reverse?

Comment: Yep, the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$formatters) now says 'The functions are called in reverse array order, each passing the value through to the next.'