# how to select multiple values from a drop down and display it in a textarea on click of submit button...?

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have to select multiple values from a drop down and display it in text area on click of a submit. I do not know  how to pass multiple values to controller and fetch it to display in a text area in same form....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the multiple attribute of the html select element and angular will create an array for you of the selected values:

```js
angular.module('MyModule', [])

.controller('MyController', function( $scope ) {
    $scope.martialArts = ['Kung Fu', 'Llap Goch', 'Karate', 'Judo'];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='MyModule' ng-controller='MyController'>
    I know
    <select multiple ng-model='whatIKnow' ng-options='martialArt for martialArt in martialArts'></select>
    <button ng-click='showWhatIKnow = true'>Show Me</button>
    <textarea ng-show='showWhatIKnow' ng-model='whatIKnow'></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: when i am using above code it is displaying [object Object] in the text area.if i am selecting two values then it showing two times [object Object].

Comment: How strange. Which browser are you using (if I run the code snippet in Chrome 38 it looks ok)?

Comment: I am using fire fox version 34.

Comment: Have only got firefox 33 but if I run the above code by pressing the 'Run code snippet' then it works as expected. Are you running the above code by pressing the 'Run code snippet' button or is it your own code that's based on the above?

Comment: it is my code based on the above code.it is still showing [object Object].. please help @Gruff Bunny

Comment: actually i am fetching the values from the data base than giving hard code values in array.....is that creating the problem..??

Comment: I suspect that you have an array of objects and not strings. The answers to this question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893708/angularjs-textarea-bind-to-json-object-shows-object-object