# I need to pre-fill a <textarea> with a json item

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have found that I can do this by with the following no problem, until I get to where I also need the  to be editable and passed back on save if updated.

Here is a directive that works to add the json data of the current item: (found on SO) - [AngularJS: textarea bind to JSON object shows "object-object"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893708/angularjs-textarea-bind-to-json-object-shows-object-object)

```
    app.directive('jsonText', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
            function into(input) {
                return JSON.parse(input);
            }
            function out(data) {
                return JSON.stringify(data);
            }
            ngModel.$parsers.push(into);
            ngModel.$formatters.push(out);

        }
    };
});
```

And here is the html, this works for the pre-filling but I am needing the ngModel to also pull in so I can save that data incase of edits.

```
<textarea json-text ng-model="review" id="review" class="form-control" rows="3"  ng-bind="encounterNote"></textarea>
```

So in the end I need a way to pre-fill a  (may be several lines of text from a jSON API), allow that to be edited and then on a save function I have already reference the "current" value to save and updates.

Comment: Why do you need to parse and serialize at all? If the API returns JSON, you should be able to treat the returned JSON as a string and make that string your model. Then you could post that model back to the API as a string again. It seems like your problem stems from having your model be a proper JS object when all you need is a JSON string.

Comment: if it is just text, none of this makes sense and it would seem you need to modify what is passed to `ng-model` What does data look like?

Answer (score 0):

@devinallenaz was correct, just using the ngModel in the textarea worked like a charm.

Now I feel dumb.