# Translate ng-model value in input

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

I'm trying to translate a value in an `input`. The input is disabled when I need to translate it so the user can't type text in the textbox. The data is inputted using `ng-model` and currently looks like this:

```
<input ng-model="reason" ng-disabled="true" type="text" class="form-control" name="reason">
```

I've also tried the following:

```
<input ng-model="reason|translate" ng-disabled="true" type="text" class="form-control" name="reason">
<input ng-model="{{ reason | translate}}" ng-disabled="true" type="text" class="form-control" name="reason">
```

but none of them worked.

I could translate the value in the controller, but I'd like to do this in the html tags so the actual value on the scope doesn't get changed.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: see this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32753082/how-to-tie-ng-model-variable-to-the-value-of-an-input-box-in-angular

Comment: @DurgpalSingh Yes, I could create a second variable in the scope to represent the translated version of the original value. But I'd prefer to avoid that and do something in the html-page instead. But thank you for the suggestion, I'll apply that when nothing else comes up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-value for inputs instead of the HTML input>value. Then you can translate them easily:

```
<input ng-value="ctrl.reason | translate" ng-model="ctrl.reason">
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with this example: think about an input with a Yes or No value that you want to be translated. Try one way data-binding in your template:

```
<input value="{{ answer | translate }}"
    type="text" class="form-control" name="answer"
    (change)="answerChanged($event)">
```

If you also want to update the value, listen for changes in the component:

```
  answerChanged(Event event) {
      this.answer = event.target.value.toUpperCase();
  }
```

Regarding the i18n files.

en.json:

```
{
  "YES": "Yes",
  "NO": "No"
}
```

fr.json:

```
{
  "YES": "Oui",
  "NO": "Non"
}
```

Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/BeYBAWG57eIZOU3KdBCD