# angularjs json two way binding to text area

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I want to two way binding to a text area that will contain json object as text, and I should able to edit the json object in textarea as two way. [working demo is here](https://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/bbhoey5g/3/)

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="GeojsonController">
    <textarea ng-model="geojson"></textarea>
    <p>Geojson is: {{geojson | json}} </p>
  </div>
</div>

angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('GeojsonController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.geojson = {
      "type": "FeatureCollection"
    };
  }]);
```

Text area content is `[object Object]`

Comment: what is `| json` doing?

Comment: @user2181397 Converts an object to a json string

Comment: `$scope.geojson` is already a json object, that is why you get `[object Object]` in your textarea, you are going to have to use `$scope.geojson` as a string and then convert the string to json.

Comment: Possible duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893708/angularjs-textarea-bind-to-json-object-shows-object-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893708/angularjs-textarea-bind-to-json-object-shows-object-object)

Answer (score 2):

```
<textarea ng-model="geojson" ng-change="update()"></textarea>

$scope.geo = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection"
};
$scope.geojson = angular.toJson($scope.geo);

$scope.update = function() {
    $scope.geo = angular.fromJson($scope.geojson);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f9fnetca/1/

P.S. Add some handling for invalid json.

Comment: i think you're right. my solution's same as yours: 
https://jsfiddle.net/bbhoey5g/5/

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson >> there is second argument: 'pretty'

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a custom directive, using [$formatters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$formatters) and [$parsers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$parsers)

```
.directive('toJson', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
     ctrl.$formatters.push(JSON.stringify);
    }
  }
});
```

`<textarea ng-model="geojson" to-json></textarea>`

Check out the Custom Validation example [in the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) to get a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `$formatters` and `$parsers` of `ng-model` to make bijection between the object in your model, and the text displayed in the input.

Hopefully, there is much simpler by working with a controller function. You show text and work on object. The getJson() method make the work

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="GeojsonController">
    <textarea ng-model="geojson"></textarea>
    <p>Geojson is: {{getJson(geojson) | json}} </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then :

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('GeojsonController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.geojson = '{"type": "FeatureCollection"}';

    $scope.getJson = function(){
        return JSON.parse($scope.geojson);
    }
  }]);
```

Here is JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/bbhoey5g/6/