# Solution for [object Object] in textarea, but using Angularjs components instead of directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, components, textarea

I ran across the exact same problem as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893708/angularjs-textarea-bind-to-json-object-shows-object-object), that is, my textarea element would display [object Object] for the ng-model binding.

I tried the solutions that were suggested i.e. using a directive, and indeed both the methods provided by "finishingmove" and "vorburger" worked.

However, my question is the following: Is there a way of implementing the same logic but with components instead of directives?

I tried to sort of adapt the given code by switching ".directive" with ".component", but "link" does not seem to be a property offered by components, and I cannot find a way of accessing my ng-model's "$parsers" and "$formatters" from inside controllers.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.