# Angular dynamic add ng-model into template

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am facing a problem... In my app I created directive that creates form fields. my idea is to pass a json object to directive with custom options for inputs, but I am expiriencing a problem with ng-model applying. Firstly here is my directive code:

```
.directive('formSelect', function () {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope:{},
        template: '<label class="acxm-dropdown {{opts.cssClass}}"><span>{{opts.labelText}}</span><select ng-transclude=""></select></label>',
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.opts = scope.$eval(attrs.opts);
        }
    };
  }
)
```

in scope.opts I would like to have an subObject with custom attributes that will be added to input, so my directive will be called:

```
<form-select opts="{labelText: 'active only', cssClass: 'acxm-p-horizontal acxm-u-inline active-filter', customAttrs: {'ng-model': 'onlyActive'}}"></form-select>
```

I tried to add ng-model attr to input dynamically but than it didn't work, I also tried to pass only the name of ng-model attr but I had also some issues... Is it possible to make it work? or not? Thanks for your help...

Comment: I managed to find a resolution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115701/angularjs-create-a-directive-that-uses-ng-model

Answer (score 0):

You can pull your ng-model out of the opts= portion, but still reference it in your directive. See the answer here as an example that I believe is close to what you're wanting to accomplish.

[$watch ngModel from inside directive using isolate scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693052/watch-ngmodel-from-inside-directive-using-isolate-scope)

Comment: Yes it is close but still i don't get quite idea of it... It observs the change of value of this field but how can I make it work with my filtering? This is what I want to achive: I have for example checkbox that should filter users in table that are active previously it was done by: ng-model="activeOnly" and than I added to table row filter:onlyActive while creating table... How can I handle this?

Comment: I don't understand.  Can you setup a jsFiddle.

Comment: ok I have something simillar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/V9e9M/1/ but based on table and there are more data :). I want to create a directive for input that will create the input with some opts passed as a parameter to the directive...

Comment: That's just a simple ng-repeat with a filter.  It really doesn't help.  Can you setup a fiddle with your attempt at the solution with the directive you have in mind.  Then I can fork it and try to get a working solution.

Comment: ok this is almost like what I am having now http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/1301/ you should have a better view on it now... Directive is compiled etc ng-model attr is on input but model dosn't work...

Comment: I believe that the compile function does not receive a scope argument. See the first answer on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164138/what-is-the-difference-between-compile-and-link-function-in-angularjs