# using angular directve to resize textarea on triggers using element.bind(event, function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a `textarea` that I want to resize on certain events using Angular directives.

What I have so far works for the event `'keydown'` but I can't seem to figure out how to get the functionality working for other events.

I also tried figuring out how I could possibly achieve this functionality without using jquery's events.

What I would like is to trigger the update function once the data has been loaded into the textarea and when the entire browser window is resized.

**Directive:**

```
var app = angular.module('directives', []);

app.directive('autoGrow', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attr){
    var update = function(event) {
      element.css('height', element[0].scrollHeight + 'px');
    }
    element.bind('keydown', update); // Works
    element.bind('load', update);    // Doesn't quite have desired effect.
    element.bind('resize', update);  // Doesn't quite have desired effect.
    update();
  }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<textarea auto-grow type="text" ng-model="model.foo">
```

Edit: Just to make sure I got my point across, all the bind elements above trigger as they are supposed to. I am just looking for a way that I can trigger my update function when: window is resized and when the ng-model changes or data is updated in the element.

Comment: can we see a fiddle? :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qwaz1Lhf/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my proposal:

1. inject the $window service to be able to register a callback to the resize event
2. specify that you custom directive requires ng-model directive to be able to watch for modelchanges

   var app = angular.module('directives', []);

   app.directive('autoGrow', function($window) {
     return {
       require: 'ngModel',
       link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl){

   ```
       scope.$watch(function () {
         return ngModelCtrl.$modelValue;
          },
          update,
          true // if deepwatch is required
          );

       var update = function(event) {
         element.css('height', element[0].scrollHeight + 'px');
       }

       element.on('keydown', update); // Works
       element.on('load', update);    // Doesn't quite have desired effect.
       element.on('resize', update);  // Doesn't quite have desired effect.
       update();

       angular.element($window).on('resize', update);
     }
   ```

   };
   });

More resources:

- [$watch ngModel from inside directive using isolate scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693052)
- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController