# Angular JS - Add ng-model to directive which is called in form

Tags: html, angularjs, datepicker, directive, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to make a **date picker** which is **filling an input text** for a **form**. I've created a **directive** for that which is called "datepicker".

But now I've a problem, **I can't use "ng-model"** on directive and I don't know how to solve this problem.
The input in the datepicker is need to be filled by the scope "projetData.dateConception" and need to be read by the form.

DatePickerDirective.js:

```
app.directive("datepicker", function(){
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    scope: {},
    templateUrl: './partials/datepicker.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){

        scope.datepicker = {};
        scope.datepicker.montListShowed = false;
        .
        .
        .
```

addProjetView.html

```
<div class = "fiche-line" ng-show="displayField.DateConception">
    <span class="fiche-field-title">Date Conception : </span> 
    <datepicker ng-model="projetData.dateConception" ></datepicker>
</div>
<div class = "fiche-line" ng-show="displayField.DateSolution">
    <span class="fiche-field-title">Date Solution : </span>
    <input type="date" ng-model="projetData.dateSolution" >
</div>
```

datepicker.html (template of the directive)

```
<div class="datepicker-relative datepicker-no-touch">
    <input ng-model="datepicker.dateSelected" class="inputDate" ng-focus="datepickerVisible = true" type="text"></input>
    <div class="datepicker-popup" ng-show="datepickerVisible">
    .
    .
    .
```

The inputs in the form:

[image: Img of the inputs in the form]

The datepicker which is filling the input

[image: Img of the datepicker which is filling the input]

In conclusion, I want to made the input generated by `<datepicker>` able to read "projetData.dateConception", modify it. And then the form, on submit, send it to my DB.(already done)

Comment: You can use Scope.$watch to pull ng-model data. Here are some good answers on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693052/watch-ngmodel-from-inside-directive-using-isolate-scope, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693052/watch-ngmodel-from-inside-directive-using-isolate-scope . @dnc253 has a demo on its use here: http://jsfiddle.net/BtrZH/5/ .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$watch ngModel from inside directive using isolate scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693052/watch-ngmodel-from-inside-directive-using-isolate-scope)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tanks for your respons, it works now !

This is how is my code now :

---

DatePickerDirective.js :

```
app.directive("datepicker", function(){
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: true,
    require: 'ngModel',
    transclude: true,
    scope: { ngModel : '='},
    templateUrl: './partials/datepicker.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){

        scope.datepicker = {};
```

---

addProjetView.html

```
<div class = "fiche-line" ng-show="displayField.DateConception">
     <span class="fiche-field-title">Date Conception : </span> 
     <datepicker ng-model="projetData.dateConception" ></datepicker>
</div>
```

---

datepicker.html (template of the directive)

```
<div class="datepicker-relative datepicker-no-touch">
        <input ng-model="ngModel" class="datepicker-input-date" type="date"></input>
</div>
```