# form element ng-model change not observered in isolate scope directive watch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Before posting this fiddle, i checked SO for similar question. Got few answer but all those were not form elements. http://jsfiddle.net/dgQAd/

I have the following questions:

1) The textbox is bound to a model `uname`, but onload the textbox is not displaying the value. why this is happening?

2)while searching for answers for this, i saw something like `require:ngModel`, and injecting a controller inside the linking function, how can i use this injected controller inside the linking function of the directive.

3)How to look for the changes in the parent scope `ng-model` from inside a linking function of an isolate scope directive.

Comment: what is ultimate goal of the directive and purpose of attaching it to the input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I've been able to get ng-model to work with an isolate scope is to use the same name for the isolate scope property:  `scope:{ "uname":"=ngModel" }`.   Your $watch will now work.
For more on this see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/14792601/215945

When a directive `require`s another directive's controller, that controller is available as the 4th option to the linking function.  In your fiddle, that is what you called `ngModel`:

```
link:function(scope,el,attrs,ngModel){
```

Normally, I prefer to name this ngModelCtrl to remind me that it is a controller.

$observe is only used with isolate scope properties that use the '@' syntax.

Comment: if possible can you point out some docs that elaborates on `require:ngModel` usage. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @rajkamal, see "Implementing custom form controls (using ngModel)" on the [forms page](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567908/watch-controller-model-value-from-inside-directive