# AngularJS form input focus, data does not show in model

Tags: angularjs, focus, angularjs-directive, setfocus, autofocus

Newbie to AngularJS, sorry.

I want certain form inputs to have focus set on them based on certain criteria.
Found that answer already **[with this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-in-angularjs) (focusMe)**.

The problem is my form input does not show up in the model.

```
    <input type='text' name='school_name' ng-model='plan.school_name' focus-me="{{true}}"/>
```

Here is a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hobbyman/pQRNv/)** to show my problem.

What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: there is some problem with jsfiddle in normal app it is working fine

Comment: No, this is the exact same behavior I'm having in my application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined a scope property on directive definition object. When you do that you create an isolated scope on top of the whole element, so that all other directives that are applied to that element (including ngModel) are also affected by it.

This issue has been addressed in other places (see "[form element ng-model change not observered in isolate scope directive watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179468/form-element-ng-model-change-not-observered-in-isolate-scope-directive-watch)", "[ngModel and component with isolated scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896732/ngmodel-and-component-with-isolated-scope/14792601#14792601)" and [github issue 1924](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1924)), but it's quite cumbersome to overcome.

Instead of defining an isolated scope, in this particular case you my access your `focus-me` attribute with `attrs` object (using $observe method):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]).directive('focusMe', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        attrs.$observe('focusMe', function(value) {
            if ( value==="true" ) {
                $timeout(function(){
                    element[0].focus();
                },5);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZshB/)